# How to create a embed for a API response for a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have added a API response to my Discord Bot and want to know how to format this API response into a embed to make it look nice when it gets sent in Discord

Here is my code:

```
const ifliveService = require("../utils/InfiniteFlightLive")
const ifl = new ifliveService()

module.exports = {
    category: "Userstats",
    description: "Fetches the users states from Discourse.",
    expectedArgs: '<ifc username>',
    minArgs: 1,
    maxArgs: 1,
    callback: async ({channel, args}) => {
        const username = args[0]
        
        const userstats = await ifl.getUserStats(username)
        if(!userstats || userstats.result == []) return "Invalid user"
        return JSON.stringify(userstats.result[0], null, '\t')
         }
     }
```

I want to return that base reply into a embed how would that be possible? Please note I am a bit of a beginner with all of this so I apologize if it is a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an embed like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Your title here")
    .setDescription("Your description here")
    .addField("Field name", "Field value");

// Using Discord.js v13
message.channel.send({ embeds: [ embed ] });
```

Add as many fields as you like using `addField()`. You can learn more about embeds in the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageEmbed).